# Breadth-First-Search in PHP

Tags: php, tree, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

My table structure is:

```
id    name           parent   lft  rgt
1     abc              0       2    3
2     def              1       4    5
3     geh              1       6    7
4     ijk              2       8    9
5     lmn              2       10   11
```

What I am doing is fetching all records first and then searching tree for all possible children using depth first search(DFS).

```
public function fetchRecursive($src_arr, $currentId, $parentFound = false)
{
    $cats = array();
    foreach ($src_arr as $row) {
        if ((!$parentFound && $row['id'] == $currentId) || $row['parent'] == $currentId) {
            $rowData = array();
            foreach ($row as $k => $v)
                $rowData[$k] = $v;
            $cats[] = $rowData;
            if ($row['parent'] == $currentId) {
                $cats = array_merge($cats, $this->fetchRecursive($src_arr, $row['id'], true));
            }
        }
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

This function is working fine and returning all children of a node.

What I am looking for is a method to get all **children of a node using BFS** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote BFS search function myself. I used [PHP's SplQueue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php)

global variable to store array of children.

```
Private $queue = [];
```

function for BFS

```
public function traverseTree($rootNode, $dummyQueue) 
{
    if($rootNode->lft != 0) {
        $dummyQueue->enqueue($rootNode->lft);
    }
    if($rootNode->rgt != 0) {
        $dummyQueue->enqueue($rootNode->rgt);
    }
    if(!($dummyQueue->isEmpty())){
        $nextId = $dummyQueue->dequeue();
        $nextNode = //get next node information using $nextId
        array_push($this->queue, $nextNode);
        $this->traverseTree($nextNode, $dummyQueue);
    }
}
```

Call traverseTree() function

```
$dummyQueue = new \SplQueue();
$this->traverseTree($id, $dummyQueue);
```

Here $id is root node for which you want to fetch all the children.

I have also added a file in [gist](https://gist.github.com/ankitraturi/b680ade46e229f962cda), suggestions and improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with two standard arrays:

```
class Node {
    protected int $value;
    protected ?Node $left;
    protected ?Node $right;

    public function __construct(int $value, ?Node $left = null, ?Node $right = null) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->left = $left;
        $this->right = $right;
    }
    
    public function breadth_first() {
        $level = [$this];
        while (count($level)) {
            $next_level = [];
            foreach ($level as $node) {
                yield $node->value;
                if ($node->left) array_push($next_level, $node->left);
                if ($node->right) array_push($next_level, $node->right);
            }
            $level = $next_level;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you could call it:

```
$tree = new Node(1,
    new Node(2,
        new Node(4),
        new Node(5)
    ),
    new Node(3)
);

foreach($tree->breadth_first() as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

BFS is not meant to get all child nodes, BFS finds the shortest path from node s to node t.
DFS how ever is visiting all nodes which seems to be more like what you are trying to do.
Also keep in mind that BFS won't go to nodes who are not reachable from the node S.

BFS cost is O(E + V) (most cases)
DFS cost is O(E + V) as well

which means you'll have no added value using BFS instead, I suggest to stick with DFS which is more efficient to your purpose.